# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using vector iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, exc-bad-access

I have a vector of vectors (a matrix) of a user-defined type, `my_type`, which is a struct and contains integers a, b, and c. I wish to define a function that finds an element of this matrix by the value of b and delete the element. Since the function doesn't know the value of c, I defined an iterator `it` to first find this element, and then set its pointer address to iterator `it_found` so that it can be used in erase() method. However, the program produced an error, `Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory,` when `it_found` is used. What is causing this error?

```
bool remove_V(int a, int b) {
    typename std::vector<my_type>::iterator it;  
    typename std::vector<my_type>::iterator it_found;  


        for(it = V.at(a).begin(); it != V.at(a).end(); ++it){
            if ((*it).b ==  1) {
                it_found == it;
                std::cerr << (*it).b << "\n";
                std::cerr << (*it_found).b << "\n";
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Assuming g++, you should try to compile with options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. If MSVC, there are comparable flags. But, the compiler *may* have warned you that the statement had no effect. I'm not sure it would have, but it's still a good practice to work under.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think:

```
it_found == it;
        ^^^^
```

should be:

```
it_found = it;
        ^^^
```

Otherwise you are dereferencing a iterator which does not point to anything valid.
Also, you might want to use the **[Remove-Erase Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Erase-Remove)**.

Answer (score 2):

You are not initializing `it_found` to any value therefore `(*it_found)` is throwing the error. I think you meant:

```
it_found = it;
```

instead of

```
it_found == it;
```